# How many ways are there of arranging eight books, two on English, in such a way that the books on English are never together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can eight books, including two of English, can be arranged in such a way that the English books are never together (i. e. next to each other)?

My Attempt:

> There are a total of $8! = 40320$ ways of arranging those eight books.

> First, we consider the case when the two English books *are* next to each other. Then these two books may be regarded as constituting a single block, and this block can appear in seven different positions, thus making for seven mutually exclusive cases.

> In each of these seven cases, there are two ways of arranging the two books on English within the block.

What next? How to proceed from here?

Comment: In the second case, there are $2\cdot7!$ possibilities, for the reasons you have given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As saulspatz notes, since there are $7!$ ways of ordering the books with the two English books together as an indistinguishable block, and therefore $2\cdot 7!$ ways of ordering the books where the English books are together, looking at the books separately, and since there are $8!$ orderings in total, there are $8!-2\cdot 7!$ orderings with the books NOT together, and thus apart, as the books either are or aren’t together so we must be able to partition the orderings this way.

$$8!-2\cdot 7!=8\cdot 7!-2\cdot 7!=(8-2)\cdot 7!=6\cdot 7!=30,240$$

If my mental maths holds true.